# Can CDI managed beans and JSF managed beans talk to each other?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean

I have a Tomcat 6 JSF web application that I'd like to set up with CDI beans.  I will have to convert the project to CDI gradually though.

My question is: can CDI beans and traditional JSF managed beans be injected into each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All JSF managed beans (JMB) either are CDI managed beans (CMB) automatically, or can be recognized as such using the *beans.xml* marker file. (The requirements of a CMB are set very low and basically just dictate the [existence of a non-parameter constructor](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#d0e794).)

This means that you should be able to use (read: inject) all JMBs with almost no extra effort.

However, problems will arise because JMBs use different scopes than CMBs (`javax.faces.*` vs. `javax.enterprise.*`)

These are best solved by registering a relative simple CDI-extension: When the CDI server (Tomcat for you) starts, it will raise a couple of events that you can observe - this is be the place where you can detect JMBs and convert them into correctly scoped CMBs.

But before you start hacking: All this has already been done by the [Seam 3 Faces module](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/scopes.html#viewscoped). Simply put it in your classpath, and all JSF-scopes are bridged to CDI-scopes.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it looks like Seam 3 Faces bridges JSF managed beans and CDI beans.