# JSF : PropertyNotFoundException The class '' does not have the property ''

Tags: java, jsf, el

Two days I'm looking for a solution to that basic problem. And YES I do have GETTER AND SETTER, and YES I really think that the convention is OK.

Here is the code :

Bean :

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ClientController implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ClientService das;
private List<Client> clientsList;
public void setClientsList(List<Client> clientsList) {
    this.clientsList = clientsList;
}

private Client client = new Client();


public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}

public void createclient(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    das.create(client);
}

public List<Client> getClientsList() {
    clientsList = das.findByNativeQuery(Client.ALL);
    return clientsList;
}

}
```

Page index.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:define name="content">

    <h:form>
        <p:panel header="Créer un Client">
            <h:outputText value="Prénom : "></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText id="clientName" value="#{clientController.client.name}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Entrez votre prénom" message="fc">
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
            </p:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Nom : "></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText id="clientLastName" value="#{clientController.client.lastName}"
                required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez votre nom"   message="fc">
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit"         
            actionListener="#{clientController.createclient}" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Error :

```
/index.xhtml @14,57 value="#{clientController.client.name}": The class 'controllers.ClientController' does not have the property 'client'.
```

As you can see, the Bean is resolved, and even the createclient() method is resolved (I tried to test it without the rest of the code). The problem is just about attributes...

Please help ? I'm sure it's a stupid problem, but sometimes we just need an other point of view

**EDIT:**

WEB-INF/web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<display-name>Bourse</display-name>

<!-- Current project stage. When it is set to 'Development' Primefaces give 
    a lot of debug information on the screen. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Staring JSF -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- JSF URL mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/manage-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

WEB-INF/manage-beans.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>clientController</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>controllers.ClientController</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
 </faces-config>
```

Comment: Can you add @ManagedBean(name="clientController")   in your class and check?

Comment: @Octopus Good idea, I just tried, but no, same problem. I do really think that the problem is not in bean name resolution. Perhaps a configuration problem in an other file ?

Comment: Do you have beans.xml or faces-config.xml?

Comment: No, and I think that is the problem, but I don't know what to put on it, where to put it. The example where I found this code (http://www.simtay.com/simple-crud-web-application-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-maven-and-jpa/) does provide some but doesn't mention the controller in it

Comment: Check out this link -http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/configure-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/. You will know how and where to define your managed beans

Comment: Ah and I have something strange when I deploy... the JSF1063 error : Setting non-serializable attribute value into HttpSession (key: clientController, value class: controllers.ClientController).

Comment: Then, your ClientController class doesn't seem to implement Serializable?? How is that?

Comment: You see it in the code it does implements Serializable... I tried to restart my glassfish and redeploy the project from scratch but it still does not recognize the Serializable implementation !!!

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code and there are several problems but I'm not sure which one is causing YOUR problem because i commented out the database stuff to make it work quickly.

I guess the main problem is that you try to use CDI together with JSF managed beans which is not supposed to work without problems.

1. You are using `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` and `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` but instead you should use `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` and `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` or even `javax.inject.Named` instead of `ManagedBean`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces) to get details about the differences.
2. The file `manage-beans.xml` you have created has content which normally belongs to the `faces-config.xml` but which is anyway obsolete because the declaration in XML is an alternative to the declaration via annotations. You don't need both. You can delete the `manage-beans.xml` and the reference in the `web.xml`. If you want to use such XML declarations you can yust put them in the `faces-config.xml`.
3. Your web.xml contains `facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS` which should be replaced with `javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS`.
4. Your project is missing a `beans.xml`. You wrote in a comment that you already created one, anyway here is a reference how it should look like:

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

See also:

- [Can CDI managed beans and JSF managed beans talk to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734214/can-cdi-managed-beans-and-jsf-managed-beans-talk-to-each-other)
- [JSF: Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/jsf-backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named)

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. That does really help me, I finally loaded the page with a tear rolling :) But now the bean is juste unreachable : identifier 'clientController' resolved to null. btw I'm trying to fix it (I opted for a @Named bean, looking into your links about any other configuration in that case)

Answer (score 0):

To enable CDI in JSF2.0 , you need to use beans.xml or faces-config.xml to define your managed beans. It is recommended to use a seperate file for configuring the beans since faces-config.xml will have application specific configuration. Please read this [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-intro.html) to gain more understanding on how CDI works. Please note that CDI works based on the JAVA EE version.

*Update:*

You need to check whether you are naming your beans correctly everywhere in your xhtml page and make sure your class and configuration files are properly loaded

Comment: I just configured both beans.xml and web.xml but the problem is the same... I will edit the post to give their content

Comment: Perhaps you cna check it in project source : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5rcDKZgM5DQRnFEU0xtZDZueFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Any idea from sources?

Comment: I am sorry, i also couldn't understand why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Besides all other problems the guys said on previous answers that you have to check, you just have a EL problem:

```
 value="# {clientController.client.lastName}"
         ^here this is not valid for EL
```

After you follow all others suggestions change this and your exception should disapear.

Comment: Hum I don't have it in my project... Perhaps a IDE config problem ? Anyway thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: Well if you copy/pasted your code it is on your index.xhtml and normally it is the cause for `PropertyNotFoundException`. But if you say that isn't, you should revise all other `value` attribute to see if it is correct mapped.

Comment: Oh you're right, seems that I made a mistake when editing the pasted code to format my post (first post here, what a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just changed the name of variable and the target folder was not reflecting the changes. So when I compile and redeploy it worked for me.